# Inplace operation on specific lines and columns of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a dataframe with negative values on specific columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, -1],[-1, 1, 1],[-1, -1, 1]])
```

Now, I want to **inplace** clip the negative values to 0 on only specific lines and columns:

```
df.loc[[1, 2], [0, 1]].clip(lower=0, inplace=True)
```

But this doesn't work:

```
df
Out: 
   0  1  2
0  1  1 -1
1 -1  1  1
2 -1 -1  1
```

This is because slicing dataframe with a list of integers returns a copy:

```
df.loc[[1, 2], [0, 1]] is df.loc[[1, 2], [0, 1]]
Out: False
```

How do I make **inplace** changes to specific rows and columns then?

Answer (score 1):

How about using [`df.lt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lt.html) instead:

```
df[df.loc[[1, 2], [0, 1]].lt(0)] = 0

print(df)

   0  1  2
0  1  1 -1
1  0  1  1
2  0  0  1
```

Comment: So the more general answer would be to use a boolean mask instead of resorting to the built-in operations.

Comment: Correct. Surely, itself also a "built-in operation" :).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
df.loc[[1, 2], [0, 1]] = df.loc[[1, 2], [0, 1]].clip(lower=0)
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2
0  1  1 -1
1  0  1  1
2  0  0  1
```

Comment: Thank you. However, this is not **inplace** operation and hence doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Ah sorry, then this is not possible. Unfortunately `.loc[]` is very annoying sometimes